# Prevent Chrome debugger from stealing focus in React Native

Tags: react-native

I use Chrome Debugging and Live Reload to debug React Native applications. 
Whenever you save a file, the Chrome screen reloads and in doing this, gets focus. This is annoying. Is there anyway to disable this focusing behaviour?

Answer (score 11):

The Chrome debug page is opened by the `launchChromeDevTools.applescript` script in the react-native package.

You can disable it grabbing the focus by opening this file in your project:

`./node_modules/react-native/packager/launchChromeDevTools.applescript`

and commenting out the `activate` line by inserting `--` in front.

(This annoyed me enough to hunt down how to do it; it might be worth filing an issue on react-native to make it an option).